# sapui5 xml view event handling leads to disappearing errors

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a sapui5 app using the version 1.108.20. I used documentation on how to handle events in xml views (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe) to implement some controls and their event handlers.

Assuming the following button:

```
<m:Button press=".onButtonPress($controller)" ></Button>
```

And the following implementation of `onButtonPress`:

```
onButtonPress: function(oController) {
    console.log(oController);
    throw new Error("Something happened")
}
```

When the button is pressed, the controller is logged as expected to the console, but the error seems to be "silently lost in the void". Neither a log or a stack trace is shown on the console.

I teste the following versions in the xml:

- `press=".onButtonPress($controller)"`
- `press=".onButtonPress.call($controller, 'fooBar')"`
- `press=".onButtonPress(${$source>/})"`
- `press=".onButtonPress('')"`

As soon as a parameter was specified in the xml, all thrown errors seem to be "swallowed". Using the same implementation of the handler in the controller, just changing the xml to `press=".onButtonPress"` results in the expected result, i.e. the error (including the stack trace) is logged to the console.

I can find no information about this in the documentation about this behaviour. I would expect the handling and logging of errors to not be influenced by the way event handlers are specified.

Comment: Don't you need to have a try/catch in order to use throw?

Comment: I can [replicate](https://jsfiddle.net/dm9f06av/1/) this issue. After some debugging, the error seems to be [trapped by the ExpressionParser](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ExpressionParser.js#L709) and logged as a warning (which is not logged on the default level).

Comment: @TiiJ7 Thank you for the replication . I cant find any explanation why this would be the desired behaviour for bindings using parameters but not for bindings without any parameters. I would expect the behaviour to be identical